# Can't read AppletViewer properties file - Applet

Tags: java, applet, appletviewer

I created a Java applet program and compiled it. As a result of the compilation, it generated a `class` file. But, it showed the following warning message while running the applet with the command prompt using the `appletviewer` command.

```
D:\Applets\Applets>appletviewer FirstApplet.java

Warning: Can't read AppletViewer properties file: C:eswaran_s.VMSPL\.hotjava\properties Using defaults.
```

When I run this command once again, it does not show the warning message, but the applet is not running.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You should give an HTML file to your applet viewer, not the Java source code.

Comment: I had the same prob even when I pass the .html file to appletviewer. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: I sometimes use the _tag-in-source_ approach, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7455045/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7455066/230513), with `-debug`.

Answer (score 9):

My solution to this problem was to simply (in Eclipse) go to Run-> Run configurations... and open the JRE card where I set Java SE to a newer installed version. (in my case from SE 6 to SE 7)

Comment: I simply did what you said. Instead of changing version just Applied again and that resolved problem.

Answer (score 2):

The file `.appletviewer` should be in your home folder. If it's not exist then default file is created. You can also place it in the `%USERPROFILE%\.hotjava\properties`.

If you run appletviewer it runs because you got any message from it. Suppose your instance is created on the `%PATH%`. But to run properly you should supply the argument text file that contains deprecated `<APPLET>` tag. It doesn't matter what extension it has.

Answer (score 1):

Your extension is wrong. You should pass HTML file path like this:

```
D:\Applets\Applets>appletviewer htmlfile_name.html
```

Instead of this:

```
D:\Applets\Applets>appletviewer FirstApplet.java
```

Answer (score 0):

It is often very difficult to write, compile and run applets in the applet viewer from the command prompt. A better way would be to download the program Eclipse from the Internet. I often got lots of errors when trying to run programs from the command prompt, and Eclipse automaticly compiles, emphasises special words (like new, break, byte, short etc.) and even error checks your code (it underlines errors with a squiggly red line like Microsoft word's spellcheck). All my problems have been solved! I seriously recommend downloading it.

Answer (score 0):

i think your jdk miss some package or loss path so re-installed jdk latest version and run your program. and check your htm program is correct or not may be some time occurred due to wrong htm program.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem following the instructions for a similar tutorial from Oracle's Java: A Beginner's Guide - Sixth Edition (pg 515). The directions tell you to immediately run the .java file with the applet viewer. However, you must first compile it. So, C:>javac FirstApplet.java. This will compile the program and create your FirstApplet class file, which is what is currently missing from your execution. Then, C:>appletviewer FirstApplet.java. Your applet should run fine. Seems odd that the tutorial would leave out this instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Shoutout to RAB teaching broken code (Applets have been deprecated in most browsers)

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the javadoc folder (simply labelled "doc" once extracted) inside your jdk folder as advised here:

http://www.jcreator.com/installation.htm

You can download the doc file from here for Java SE 8:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jdk8-doc-downloads-2133158.html

Make sure you build the project first before running it (Menu/Build/Build Project).

Now run your project.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using command line to run the file, use this particular line after importing packages.

```
/*<applet code = "Class_name.class" width=300 height=250></applet>*/
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I have change this line in the prompt and ready:

```
D:\Applets\Applets>appletviewer FirstApplet.java
```