# ClassNotFound Exception when calling Applet

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, applet

I am trying to set up a simple `JApplet` using IntelliJ. I have a class called `Square` and a HTML file which should make it work, but I keep getting a `ClassNotFoundException`.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Square extends JApplet {

    int size = 40;

    public void init() {
        JButton butSmall = new JButton("Small");
        JButton butMedium = new JButton("Medium");
        JButton butLarge = new JButton("Large");
        JButton butMessage = new JButton("Say Hi!");

        SquarePanel panel = new SquarePanel(this);
        JPanel butPanel = new JPanel();
        butPanel.add(butSmall);
        butPanel.add(butMedium);
        butPanel.add(butLarge);
        butPanel.add(butMessage);
        add(butPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}

class SquarePanel extends JPanel {

    Square theApplet;

    SquarePanel(Square app) {
        theApplet = app;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(20, 20, theApplet.size, theApplet.size);
    }
}
```

and the HTML file

```
<HTML>
<APPLET CODE="Square.class"> WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=200>
</APPLET>
</HTML>
```

This is the folder structure. I've tried lots of different combos and names and <> delimiters but I can't get it to open properly.

[image: folder image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the applet container, typically a browser, has been told where to find the class `Square` but not the class `SquarePanel`. You can do either of two things:

- Enclose your classes in a JAR and specify the `archive` name in your `<APPLET\>` tag, as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html).
- Nest `SquarePanel` in `Square`, as shown below for illustration purposes.

A JAR is the preferred approach, but also consider a [hybrid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12449889/230513) for more flexible testing and deployment. For convenient `appletviewer` testing, the  tag is included in a comment, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7455066/230513).

[image]

Command line:

```
$ appletviewer Square.java
```

Code, as tested:

```
// <applet code='Square' width='400' height='200'></applet>
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Square extends JApplet {

    int size = 40;

    public void init() {
        JButton butSmall = new JButton("Small");
        JButton butMedium = new JButton("Medium");
        JButton butLarge = new JButton("Large");
        JButton butMessage = new JButton("Say Hi!");

        SquarePanel panel = new SquarePanel(this);
        JPanel butPanel = new JPanel();
        butPanel.add(butSmall);
        butPanel.add(butMedium);
        butPanel.add(butLarge);
        butPanel.add(butMessage);
        add(butPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private static class SquarePanel extends JPanel {

        Square theApplet;

        SquarePanel(Square app) {
            theApplet = app;
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillRect(20, 20, theApplet.size, theApplet.size);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See also [*Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets*](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) and [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).