# Issue in run java applet program

Tags: java, applet

I'm new to java:
When i'm studying package, there are lots of packages available in java platform.

This is my code:

```
package day1.examples;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class HelloWorld extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello world!", 50, 25);
    }
}
```

When i run this code, it shows this warning :"The import java.applet is never used"

My page look like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: it is not error. it is just warning. the code should work fine

Comment: @adem: how to view the output.. i mean,, how to add println? or how to fix the warning/

Comment: right click on the code, select "run as" -> "Java Applet"

Comment: I have only "run as" -> "Run configurations.."

Comment: eclipse should detect your class is an applet. but, if not, select "run configurations" and then select "Java Applet" on new window. but,  I am almost sure eclipse should be able to detect it is an applet. are you sure you are doing this when your applet code is open ?

Comment: My class is HelloWorld.java

Comment: are you trying to extend `java.applet.Applet` or your `Applet` class in your package.

Comment: @johny you are right. sss has another class that named Applet. try to extend java.applet.Applet , or remove your Applet class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are extending the `Applet` class in your package. To use the `java.applet.Applet` you have to either remove Applet from your package or do the following

```
import java.awt.*;
public class HelloWorld extends java.applet.Applet {
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      g.drawString("Hello world!", 50, 25);
   }
}
```

Comment: i got the warning Warning: Can't read AppletViewer properties file: C:\Documents and Settings\Ephrem\.hotjava\properties Using defaults. and what is the problem if i use "import java.applet.*;"

Comment: @sss check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703078/cant-read-appletviewer-properties-file-applet

Comment: `g.drawString("Hello world!", 50, 25)` prints `Hello world!` at the coordinate (50,25).

Comment: sorry, what is that name(technically), in this program, and what is Graphis g? Thanks.

Comment: Graphics is a class which has different methods used for displaying image, text, etc.. inside your applet.